# How to get the value from textfield to forward page?

Tags: jsp

Am New to jsp I had to forward the name from one file to another,I am getting that name from textField (name represents another JSP file name). After a lot of dig I found the below code to be worked but it wasn't work. I have three jsp files like oneMain.jsp, twoMain.jsp and threeMain.jsp. I forward the name threeMain from oneMain.jsp to twoMain.jsp. So that I can display the content of the threeMain.jsp page

oneMain.jsp code is

```
<input type="text" id="first" name="firstPage" value="twoMain.jsp">  
<input type="text" id="second" name="secondPage" value="threeMain.jsp">  
<jsp:forward page=<%request.getParameter("firstPage")%>>  
<jsp:param name="visualName" value=<%request.getParameter("secondPage")%>/>  
</jsp:forward>
```

twoMain.jsp code is

```
<%response.sendRedirect(request.getParameter("visualName"));%>
```

Finally I want threeMain.jsp content to be displayed.

Comment: Have you written above code in the form? How are you accessing these parameters in secondPage.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Try using <%= in place of <%

Like following code and see if it works:

```
<jsp:forward page="<%=request.getParameter("firstPage")%>">  
<jsp:param name="visualName" value="<%=request.getParameter("secondPage")%>"/>  
</jsp:forward>
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? This thing doesn't even compile in Netbeans. If you surround `<%=...%>` in `"` then it does compiles but throws this exception `Attribute value request.getParameter("firstPage") is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value`

Comment: @Pranav,@MaVRoSCy I am also getting same problem..

Comment: Sorry my mistake, with value attribute you cant use "".
Try using single ' in place of "". And let me know.

Comment: @Pranav I tried like this `<jsp:forward page='<%=request.getParameter("firstPage")%>'>`,and I am getting this error `/firstMain.jsp(21,36) quote symbol expected`

Comment: I believe you cant use request.getParameter() to get data from the same jsp page...Try it like this and it works for sure: 
oneMain.jsp:
<input type="text" id="first" name="firstPage" value="twoMain.jsp"> <input type="text" id="second" name="secondPage" value="threeMain.jsp"> <jsp:forward page="oneMain.jsp"> 
<jsp:param name="visualName" value="twoMain.jsp"/> 
</jsp:forward> 
twoMain.jsp: 
<%response.sendRedirect(request.getParameter("visualName"));%>